# Pass data with ajax in laravel, it does not detect my method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to pass records through a checkbox using ajax and jquery, the problem is that when executing my function it returns an empty array, at the moment I am testing but it does not let me advance.
my script

```
 <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
               $('.save_btn').on('click',function(e){
                   e.preventDefault();
                   const prodid= [];
                   const prodname = [];
                   $('.prod-id').each(function(){
                       if($(this).is(":checked")){
                           prodid.push($(this).val());
                       }
                   });
                   $('input[name^="prodname"]').each(function(){
                      prodname.push($(this).val());
                   });
                   $.ajax({
                     url:'{{ route('save_data') }}',
                     type: 'POST',
                     data: {
                      "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                      prodid: prodid
                     },
                     success:function(response){
                     }
                   });
           });
           });
       </script>
```

At the moment I am only passing a parameter of an input for the test but it is not being passed inside the array.

```
    <tbody>
                               @foreach($ventas1 as $ventas)
                               <tr>
                                   <td>
                                      <input type="checkbox" name="prodid" id="prod-id" value="mobile">
                                   </td>
                                   <td> {{ date("d-m-Y",strtotime($ventas->FECHA)) }}</td>
                                <td>   <input name="prodname[]" class="prod-name" id="moneda" value={{$ventas->MONEDA}} readonly> </td>
                                {{--   <td><input type="text">{{$ventas->MONEDA}}</td> --}}
                                   <td>{{$ventas->NUMCTA}}</td>
                                   <td>{{$ventas->CONCEPTO}}</td>
                                   <td>{{$ventas->FACTURA}}</td>
                                   <td>{{$ventas->DENOMINACION_SOCIAL}}</td>
                                   <td>{{$ventas->VENDEDOR}}</td>
                                   <td>${{$ventas->IMPORTE}}</td>
                                   {{-- <td>${{$ventas->IMPORTEEXT}}</td> --}}
                               </tr>
                               @endforeach
                           </tbody>
```

This is my route where I am passing the data to the function in my controller
`Route::get('save_data',[ventas1Controller::class,'save_data'])->name('save_data');` 
And this is my controller, I am using a dd to be able to see the array with the data that I am passing but it is not passing said data

```
 public function save_data(Request $request) {
       dd($request->all());
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You route is expecting GET method but you are requesting POST method from your AJAX request as a result method is not found. Try the below script.

**UPDATE:**

As you are using AJAX request in Laravel so you maye face issue related to CSRF Token if it not setup properly. So, to fix that follow the below steps and updated script;

Add the meta tag in your application master blade file under **head** tag.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Then add this script in you master blade file inside body tag bottom.

```
<script>
        $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') } });
</script>
```

And this updated script.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.save_btn').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            let prodid= [];
            let prodname = [];
            $('.prod-id').each(function(){
                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                    prodid.push($(this).val());
                }
            });
            $('input[name^="prodname"]').each(function(){
                prodname.push($(this).val());
            });
            $.ajax({
                url:`{{ route('save_data') }}`,
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                   prodid: prodid
                },
                success:function(response){
                    
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it returns only this

Comment: array:1 [▼
  "_token" => "4V7yGk9t8GcvBXzJoRzyY51qB6qIkqDJSjvfnrW4"
]

Comment: Can you please elaborate more ``it only return this`` means? And you are using the above script in you blade file, right?

Comment: If I'm using the script you gave me, and I'm also using it in my blade file, actually this should be with post but if I change the path to post it gives me another error

Comment: @BrayanGalvantry try the update answer, You may face issue because of CSRF token not setup properly for AJAX request.

Comment: @BrayanGalvan you can add your screenshot link in comment, by the way the image is not loading.

Comment: It returns all the records even if I have not selected them, this is due to the foreach() you do not know any way to solve this

Comment: So your method not found and data get issue solved? If yes then you can mark the issue as solved :). And yes there are way to filter your selected values. let me know your scenario more details.

Comment: Hello! I did it in a different way using select from datatables now I am trying to pass the data to my controller

Comment: ```$('#Enviar').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('#form').find('input[type="hidden"]').remove();
  var seleccionados = table.rows({ selected: true });

  if(!seleccionados.data().length)
    alert("No ha seleccionado ninguna venta");
  else{
    seleccionados.every(function(key,data){
      console.log(this.data());

      $('<input>', {
          type: 'hidden',
          value: this.data()[1],
          name: 'ids[]'
      }).appendTo('#form');

      //$("#form").submit(); //submiteas el form
    });
  }
});```